# Multiple Indirects with named range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to write a formula using SUMPRODUCT, SUMIF, INDIRECT and a named range. My formula is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("EightiesNames")&"'!G8:HI8"),$A$2,INDEX(INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("EightiesNames")&"'!G9:HI300"),MATCH($A$1,INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("EightiesNames")&"'!E9:E300"),0),0)))
```

The formula goes through every worksheet in the named range and does a lookup to both the columns (looking up $A$2 in G8:HI8. note that $A$2 may occur multiple times in one worksheet) and rows (looking up $A$1 to E9:E300) before summing together all the return values with SUMIF/SUMPRODUCT.

The formula was inspired by the below simplified version but with SUMPRODUCT and INDIRECT layered in to allow it to perform the same function across multiple tabs.

```
=SUMIF(G8:HI8, $A$2, INDEX(G9:HI300, MATCH($A$1, E9:E300,0), 0))
```

See below for a more detailed description of the workbook.

Worksheets:

*Sheet1* - houses a named range in cells B2:B7 `{Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5, Name6}`. The named range is called "*EightiesNames*"

*Name1* - where the formula is located. The formula references worksheets *Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5, Name6*, basically all the worksheets in the named range.

There are three occurrences of `"INDIRECT("'"&INDIRECT("EightiesNames")"` - after the SUMIF, one after INDEX and after the MATCH. The first occurrence of the two INDIRECTs, works the way I want it to (when I evaluate the formula). It expands the `INDIRECT("EightiesNames")` into an array *{"Name1";"Name2";"Name3";"Name4";"Name5";"Name6"}*. The formula then proceeds to tack on the range *"'!G8:HI8"* after each "Name" - `"'Name1'!G8:HI8";...;"'Name6'!G8:HI8"`.
However, for the INDIRECTs that occur after the INDEX and the MATCH, it does not return an array like the first one. On my computer, it returns "*Name2*" (returns "*Name1*" on my friend's), not sure why its different and why it returns those values instead of the entire array.

I'm not really sure how to fix this as the three INDIRECT formulas are identical but do not produce the same result. I also know INDIRECT formulas take up a lot of processing power so I'll gladly take alternatives. Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While a single formula solution is possible, it would be very complex, inefficient, and not robust at all.  For this reason, I would suggest that you use a regular SUMIF formula for each worksheet, where it would be placed in the same cell for each of your worksheets, let's say B1, and then you could simply use SUM to get your total, for example `=SUM('Sheet1:Sheet5'!B1)`.

However, if you would like to try a single formula solution, try the following formula that needs to be confirmed with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Note that I have assumed that G8:HI8 and E9:E300 for each of your worksheets contain text values.  If G8:HI8 contains numerical values, replace...

```
T(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&EightiesNames&"'!G8:HI8"),,COLUMN(INDIRECT("G8:HI8"))-7,,1))=$A$2
```

with

```
N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&EightiesNames&"'!G8:HI8"),,COLUMN(INDIRECT("G8:HI8"))-7,,1))=$A$2
```

Also, if E9:E300 contains numerical values, replace...

```
T(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(EightiesNames)&"'!E9:E300"),ROW(INDIRECT("9:300"))-9,0,1))=$A$1
```

with

```
N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(EightiesNames)&"'!E9:E300"),ROW(INDIRECT("9:300"))-9,0,1))=$A$1
```

Here's the formula...

```
=SUM(IF(T(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&EightiesNames&"'!G8:HI8"),,COLUMN(INDIRECT("G8:HI8"))-7,,1))=$A$2,N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&EightiesNames&"'!G9:HI9"),TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("9:300")))^0,IF(T(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(EightiesNames)&"'!E9:E300"),ROW(INDIRECT("9:300"))-9,0,1))=$A$1,ROW(INDIRECT("9:300"))-9,0))),COLUMN(INDIRECT("G9:HI9"))-7,,1)),0))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Domenic - thanks for your response! The first option isn't possible for me as the worksheet names/amount of worksheets are ever changing. Would be a pain to input a new 'SUMIF' with every change. I tried writing the array formula you gave me. I don't really understand it but I get the gist of what it's trying to accomplish. I ran through it using evaluate formula and it seems to work as intended. However, it is returning 0 as the final value (I expected another value). Not sure how to troubleshoot this formula.

Comment: Are the values in G8:HI8 and E9:E300 text values or numerical values?  If the latter, you'll need to change T(OFFSET(INDIRECT(...))) to N(OFFSET(INDIRECT(...))), as I mentioned in my post.

Comment: One of them is a text, the other is more question since they have numbers and dashes (zip code), so I classified it as a text as well. I basically kept your formulas with the T for those two instances.

Comment: I'm assuming that you've confirmed the formula with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, correct?

Comment: Also, have you made any changes to the formula?  If so, can you post the exact formula that you're using?

Comment: I made a slight change to the range of the rows (I tried it with the original formula too but it didn't work either). And yes i did CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER to make it an array. SUM(IF(T(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&EightiesNames&"'!G8:HI8"),,COLUMN(INDIRECT("G8:HI8"))-7,,1))=G$8,N(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&EightiesNames&"'!G10:HI10"),TRANSPOSE(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("10:300")))^0,IF(T(OFFSET(INDIRECT("'"&TRANSPOSE(EightiesNames)&"'!E10:E300"),ROW(INDIRECT("10:300"))-10,0,1))=$C$3,ROW(INDIRECT("10:300"))-10,0))),COLUMN(INDIRECT("G10:HI10"))-8,,1)),0))

Comment: Also, do you have any idea why my INDIRECT(NamedRange) does not return my array when placed in an INDEX MATCH? It returns the array in the INDEX but not the subsequent MATCH. =INDEX(EightiesNames&"!A1:A2",MATCH(A1,INDIRECT(EightiesNames&"!A2:A3"),0))

Comment: At the end of the formula, it should be `-7`, not `-8`.  So it should be `COLUMN(INDIRECT("G10:HI10"))-7`.

Comment: Updated to be -7, not change in the result though.

Comment: Can you edited your post and include a screenshot of about 10 to 20 rows of sample data, along with the values you have in both G8 and C3, starting at E8?